# Programmatical naming variable c#

Tags: c#, foreach, variable-assignment

I have a large amount of nested foreach loops and I'm running out of variable names to use...
Could I do something like this :

```
 //int i = 1
 string "number"+i = new String("FirstElement");
```

I've seen some posts about this for languages such as C and javascript, but I don't know how to do it in C#.

In case you can't name variables after other variables : how could this problem otherwise be solved?

Comment: Maybe use array, list or other collection? So you can access them like `number[1]` instead of `number1`

Comment: and how could I implement that option into a foreach variable declaration? (eg foreach([VAR] in ~~~)?

Comment: @user2698666 could you try that: string "number" + i.ToString() = new String("FisrtELement")

Comment: Nested foreaches: if you can't handle the variables, you have a **big problem**.

Comment: string "number" + i.toString() = new String("FisrtELement")  doesn't work

Comment: @user2698666 t must be bigger. like : i.ToString()

Comment: yes but even then an error occurs

Comment: @B.K. you definitely can't do that... it's invalid sintax for c#, you can't define a variable name that way

Comment: Your running out of variable names?... How is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

This problem could *otherwise* be solved by using meaningful variable names - running out of names would mean running out of concepts for what the thing is trying to achieve, which is hard to believe.

If your requirement is to work with a collection of variables, then put them in a collection; if it's to have *n* number of variables all strictly defined by name, then name them explicitly, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = new List<int>(); 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
{    
     a.Add(i); 
}
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
Console.WriteLine(a[1]);
etc....
```

This way you make list which contains 100 elements, you can access them by `nameoflist[index]`

Comment: and how could I implement that option into a foreach variable declaration? (eg foreach([VAR] in ~~~)?

Comment: @user2698666 `foreach(var something in yourmagiclist) { a.Add(something.SomeProperty); } ` of course `a` must be a list of same type as `SomeProperty`

Comment: You do something like (foreach String str in listOfStrings){myMethod(str);}etc

Answer (score 1):

A while back I asked a similar question:

[Python - neat way of creating multiple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126710/python-neat-way-of-creating-multiple-objects)

Basically, if you have lots of very similar variables named things like variable_1, variable_2, etc, then thats normally a sign that you should be using an array or list of variables instead.

So instead of 10 separate string variables, create a list (or array) of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing will not work in C#. You can not create variables at run time. If you want 
you have to use a list to store your variable name and value. Therefore you better create a class to hold name of the variable and value.

```
class Variable
{
   string Name;
   string  Value;
}
```

Now create another class to hold variables

```
class VaraibleHolder
{
    List<Variable> Variables;
    VariableHolder()
    {
        Variables = new List<Variables>(); 
    } 

    public void Add(Variable Vbl)
    {
        Variable vbl = Variables.SingleOrDefault(v=>v.Name == Vbl.Name);
        if(vbl == null)
        {
            Variables.Add(vbl);  
        } 
    }

    public void Remove(string VblName)
    {
        //this is a lamda expression.
        Variable vbl = Variables.SingleOrDefault(v=>v.Name == VblName);
        if(vbl != null)
        {
            Variables.Remove(vbl);  
        }    
    }

    public Variable GetVariable(string VblName)
    {
         Variable vbl = Variables.SingleOrDefault(v=>v.Name == VblName);
         return vbl;  
    } 
}
```

So you can use Variable holder to create and store varaibles at runtime. Hope this will help you.

Comment: well it would be easier to use directly a Dictionary<string,string>